# datatable in shiny populate an initial table and let the user update one of the columns and when they click update the other columns should change

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a project that involves optimization and the optimized results will be displayed in the UI as a datatable. However, the values that should be optimized should be editable so that the user can experiment optimizing various values. I have a very simple example below. There is an initial dataframe with budget and the budget is distributed for mrA and mrB. Now, what if I want to change any of the budget values and when clicking an update button, get new values for mrA and mrB columns?

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
initial_budget = tibble(country = c('us', 'fr', 'de'),
                        budget = c(100, 200, 300))

ui <- fluidPage(

   DT::dataTableOutput('allocated')
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$allocated = DT::renderDataTable({
    df = initial_budget
    df = df %>% mutate(mrA = budget * 0.25,
                       mrB = budget * 0.75)
    df
    
  })

    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Also see edited answer below for example where an update button is included to change `mrA` and `mrB` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief demo that may help.

Create a `reactiveVal`ue that will store your budget (initially set to `initial_budget`).

Create a `proxy` to manipulate the data table. With an `observeEvent` you can track edits and then update the reactive data.frame.

An additional `observe` will recalculate the other values when the data has been modified.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

initial_budget = tibble(country = c('us', 'fr', 'de'),
                        budget = c(100, 200, 300))

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('allocated')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(initial_budget)
  
  observe({
    df(mutate(df(), mrA = budget * 0.25, mrB = budget * 0.75))
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('allocated')
  
  observeEvent(input[["allocated_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["allocated_cell_edit"]]
    df(editData(df(), info, proxy))
  })
  
  output$allocated <- DT::renderDataTable(df(), editable = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit**: For a version of the app that only updates the table when a button is clicked, you could try the following.

Add an `actionButton` to your `ui`. Tie an `observeEvent` to your action button that will recalculate `mrA` and `mrB` when clicked. The `ignoreNULL` is set to FALSE so that the calculations are done initially (if the data already has default values in `initial_budget` this may not be needed).

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

initial_budget = tibble(country = c('us', 'fr', 'de'),
                        budget = c(100, 200, 300))

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('allocated'),
  actionButton("update", "update")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(initial_budget)
  
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    df(mutate(df(), mrA = budget * 0.25, mrB = budget * 0.75))
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('allocated')
  
  observeEvent(input[["allocated_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["allocated_cell_edit"]]
    df(editData(df(), info, proxy))
  })
  
  output$allocated <- DT::renderDataTable(df(), editable = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```